# I get an error when I wanted to call an empty list of a value in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below

```
[{
  “a”: {
    “uuid”: “4458”,
    “created_at”: “2022-10-19 12:20”,
    “source_platform”: “abc”,
    “platform”: “UK”
  },
  “b”:[],
  “c”: [],
  “d”: [],
  “f”: [],
  “e”: [],
  “g”: [],
  “h”: [],
  “i”: [],
  “j”: {}
}]
```

and I need to return 'no_info' if the list of a key such as 'b' or 'j' is empty.

but when I use this function

```
def get_lead_first_platform(data: dict) -> str:
        try:
            if isinstance(data.get('b'), list):
                if data.get('b')[0].get('ad_source'):
                    return data.get('b')[0].get('ad_source')
                else:
                    return 'no_info'
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'{inspect.stack()[0][3]} -- {e}')
            return None
```

it gives me this error `get_lead_first_platform -- 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the empty check before accessing the list.

```
def get_lead_first_platform(data: dict) -> str:
    try:
        if isinstance(data.get('b'), list):
            if len(data.get('b')[0]) > 0:
                return data.get('b')[0].get('ad_source')
            else:
                return 'no_info'
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'{inspect.stack()[0][3]} -- {e}')
        return None
```

Comment: still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You do not "have a dictionary" as you stated. What you have here is a list with a dictionary within it. Hence if you pass it to your function you are actually calling `.get()` on a list.

So `data.get("b")` would be

```
   [{
  “a”: {
    “uuid”: “4458”,
    “created_at”: “2022-10-19 12:20”,
    “source_platform”: “abc”,
    “platform”: “UK”
  },
  “b”:[],
  “c”: [],
  “d”: [],
  “f”: [],
  “e”: [],
  “g”: [],
  “h”: [],
  “i”: [],
  “j”: {}
}].get("b")
```

Maybe try executing `get_lead_first_platform(data[0])`.

Edit:

After fixing the error with `.get()` you will run into an "index out of range" error with the statement `data.get('b')[0]` if the `list` "b" is empty.